# filter just a portion of plugin function

Tags: plugins, functions, filters

I'm trying to edit just a few pieces of bbpress' breadcrumb default settings, but the filters I've tried end up replacing the whole function. How do you replace only bits? Here is the filter as it stands now

```
function custom_bbp_breadcrumb() {
    $args = array (
        'before'  => '<div class="bbp-breadcrumb">',
        'after'   => '</div>',
        'sep'     => __( '&rsaquo;', 'bbpress' ),
    );
    return $args;
}

add_filter('bbp_get_breadcrumb', 'custom_bbp_breadcrumb' );
```

I could copy + paste the whole function and filter that, but that would be extremely inefficient.

Comment: Why was my question down voted? You should at least include a comment as to what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that isn't the filter the want. It runs right at the end of the BBPress [`bbp_get_breadcrumb`](http://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.0/bbp-includes/bbp-common-template.php#L1417) function which is after the stuff you want to change.

You can change just the separator with [`bbp_breadcrumb_separator`](http://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.0/bbp-includes/bbp-common-template.php#L1621) and it looks like before and after can be set with [`bbp_get_breadcrumb_pre`](http://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.0/bbp-includes/bbp-common-template.php#L1541). In fact, it looks like you should be able to use that last filter for all of them.

I don't run BBPress so this is untested but what you want probably looks like:

```
function custom_bbp_breadcrumb() {
    $args['before']  = '<div class="bbp-breadcrumb">';
    $args['after']   = '</div>';
    $args['sep']     = __( '&rsaquo;', 'bbpress' );
    return $args;
}
add_filter('bbp_before_get_breadcrumb_parse_args', 'custom_bbp_breadcrumb' );
```

What you were doing with your filter function was completely erasing the input. You created a brand new array inside your filter function and sent that new array back out. What the modified filter does is take the input, alter it, and give it back with only some parts changed and everything else left alone.

Comment: This has syntax errors in it that results in a blank page. I'm not sure _what_ syntax errors since I'm still learning this stuff...

Comment: I see the errors. :( Give me a second. I didn't replace the commas with semi-colons.

Comment: It turns out the filter target was `bbp_before_get_breadcrumb_parse_args` and no `$args` is needed in the filter name. I have zero idea why that filter works. I can't find it anywhere in bbpress' functions... I guess I just don't understand fully how these things work yet. If you adjust your anser I'll mark it the solution.

Comment: I can't find that hook in the source code either. I am puzzled by that too.

Comment: Glad it's not just me. I feel like I'm in bizzarroland